# Standard ML - Return the index of the occurrences of a given value in a list

Tags: recursion, sml, ml

I'm trying to figure out how to return a list of the indexes of occurrences of a specific value in another list.
i.e.
indexes(1, [1,2,1,1,2,2,1]);
val it = [1,3,4,7] int list

I'm trying to figure out how lists work and trying to get better at recursion so I don't want to use List.nth (or any library functions) and I don't want to move into pattern matching quiet yet.

This is what I have so far

```
fun index(x, L) =
if null L then 0
else if x=hd(L) then 
    1
else 
    1 + index(x,tl L);

fun inde(x, L) =
if null L then []
else if x=hd(L) then 
    index(x, tl L) :: inde(x, tl L)
else
    inde(x, tl L);

index(4, [4,2,1,3,1,1]);

inde(1,[1,2,1,1,2,2,1]);
```

This gives me something like [2, 1, 3, 0]. I guess I'm just having a hard time incrementing things properly to get the index. The index function itself works correctly though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead you could also make two passes over the list: first add an index to each element in the list, and second grap the index of the right elements:

```
fun addIndex (xs, i) =
    if null xs then []
    else (hd xs, i) :: addIndex(tl xs, i+1)

fun fst (x,y) = x
fun snd (x,y) = y
fun indexi(n, xs) =
    if fst(hd xs) = n then ... :: indexi(n, tl xs)
    else indexi(n, tl xs)
```

(I left out part of `indexi` for the exercise.)
Where `addIndex([10,20,30],0)` gives you `[(10,0),(20,1),(30,2)]`. Now you can use `addIndex` and `indexi` to implement your original `index` function:

```
fun index(n, xs) = indexi(n, addIndex(xs, 0))
```

When you get that to work, you can try to merge `addIndex` and `indexi` into one function that does both.

However, you really want to write this with pattern matching, see for instance `addIndex` written using patterns:

```
fun addIndex ([], _) = []
  | addIndex (x::xs, i) = (x,i) :: addIndex(xs, i+1)
```

Comment: That makes sense but what I cant figure out how to do is how would one feed JUST the list L to the indexi function, and then have the same results? I can't feed a tuple to indexi (which is the only way I can find to do this)

Answer (score 0):

If you do index(1,[2]), it gives 1, which is not correct. When the list is empty, it gives you zero. In a function like this, you'd probably want to use SOME/NONE feature.